# Conflict for solving denoising problem as optimization problem by gradient descent method

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization, gradient-descent, image-processing

I am new to image processing and optimization.
Let y be a noisy image described by the relationship y = x+n, where u is a noise-free image and n is the noise. The goal is to recover x from n.

min || y-x ||^2_2+lambda|| x ||^2_2

It should be solved by the gradient method for the optimization problem. Here is the code that I wrote, but I cannot get the correct answer. If anyone can help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from PIL import Image
from skimage import  img_as_float
from skimage.util import random_noise
import math
from numpy import linalg as LA
from skimage.metrics import peak_signal_noise_ratio
import scipy.ndimage.filters

#define image
img = img_as_float(np.random.random((2, 2)))
#define noise
noise = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(2,2))*0.2
#add noise to image
img_noise=img+noise

p = 0.0001  #gradient step
N = 600 #number of iterations 
Lambda = 5
Cur_u = img_noise
weight_history = []
print('img=',img)
for k in range(N):
  Prev_u=Cur_u
  Cur_u = Prev_u - p*(2*(Prev_u-img_noise)+2*Lambda*Prev_u)
  weight_history.append(Cur_u)
  [enter image description here][1]

print(weight_history)
psnr = peak_signal_noise_ratio(img,img_noise)
psnr = peak_signal_noise_ratio(img,weight_history[-1])
```

I want that the denoising image becomes more closer to the original image. But I do not see any denoising. I cannot see any difference between noise and denoising. I use psnr and it shows that no change happens. I change learning rate and iteration but I do not see any correct result.

Comment: This site is about math and not about coding. Do you have a question about math?

Comment: What's the idea behind the line `deltau = scipy.ndimage.filter.laplace(Prev_u)`? I don't see what that `laplace` function has to do with anything.

Comment: @littleO
It is the gradient of regularization part. Gradient of tikhonov regularization is laplacian.

Comment: The gradient of the function $R(x) = \lambda \| x \|_2^2$ is just $2\lambda x$. It's worthwhile to learn how to compute these gradients, btw.

Comment: @littleO
At first I use matrix derivative and calculus and I write it $2\lambda x$. I do not get correct answer. I saw in some paper they use the derivative of  tikhonov regularization, so  I use it.

Comment: Don’t blindly do things that don’t make sense! Your gradient $2\lambda x$ was correct and using the Laplace function is totally wrong. If you fix that error it looks to me like your code should work. You should make that correction, post your updated code, and tell us what happens when you run it.

Comment: By the way, for image denoising it would be more common to take your regularization term to be $R(x) = \lambda \| D x \|_2^2$, where $D$ is a discrete gradient operator. The gradient of this function $R$ is $\nabla R(x) = 2 \lambda D^T D x$, and $D^T D$ could be described as a discrete Laplace operator. The paper you looked at is probably doing that, or something similar to that. Other regularization terms such a total variation regularization can also be used.

Comment: @littleO
thank you so much for your comment! I get your point. At first I try it to solve simple problem so I consider D=I.
I again correct it as the way I did it before and you told me. I do not get correct answer.

Comment: There’a a minus sign in your expression for the gradient of the regularization term that shouldn’t be there. Once you fix that I bet it will work. If you compute the objective function value at each iteration, you can make a plot to check that the objective function value is doing down.

Comment: @littleO
I corrected it. Unfortunately, I do not see any any improvement in the result. I cannot find where is my mistake

Comment: A very important way to check if your optimization algorithm is working is to make a plot of the objective function value versus iteration, and see if the objective function is going down. I think that would help clarify what's going on here.